# How to upgrade from angular-strap-0.7.5

Tags: angularjs, angular-strap

I've inherited a project using angular-strap-0.7.5.

I've upgraded Angular from 0.10 to 1.6.4, and resolved most of the problems (very few, btw).

However, bsPopover is crashing and here's the stack trace:

```
angular.js:14525 Error: [$http:badreq] Http request configuration url must be a string or a $sce trusted object.  Received: undefined
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.4/$http/badreq?p0=undefined
    at http://localhost.auspost.com.au:4445/lib/js/vendor/node_modules/angular/angular.js:66:12
    at $http (http://localhost.auspost.com.au:4445/lib/js/vendor/node_modules/angular/angular.js:11967:30)
    at Function.$http.(anonymous function) [as get] (http://localhost.auspost.com.au:4445/lib/js/vendor/node_modules/angular/angular.js:12237:18)
    at Object.postLink [as link] (http://localhost.auspost.com.au:4445/lib/js/vendor/angular-strap-0.7.5/angular-strap.js:564:71)
    at http://localhost.auspost.com.au:4445/lib/js/vendor/node_modules/angular/angular.js:1346:18
    at invokeLinkFn (http://localhost.auspost.com.au:4445/lib/js/vendor/node_modules/angular/angular.js:10426:9)
    at nodeLinkFn (http://localhost.auspost.com.au:4445/lib/js/vendor/node_modules/angular/angular.js:9815:11)
    at compositeLinkFn (http://localhost.auspost.com.au:4445/lib/js/vendor/node_modules/angular/angular.js:9055:13)
    at compositeLinkFn (http://localhost.auspost.com.au:4445/lib/js/vendor/node_modules/angular/angular.js:9058:13)
    at nodeLinkFn (http://localhost.auspost.com.au:4445/lib/js/vendor/node_modules/angular/angular.js:9809:11) "
<span class="remove ng-scope" generic-modal="/content/projects/modal/project-delete.html" ng-click="deleteProject=listProject" bs-popover="popover.content" data-placement="left" data-content="Delete this project" data-trigger="hover">"
```

I've tried upgrading to this one: http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/

Now I don't get a stack trace or any errors, but the popover just shows the dark background (mask) and does nothing else.

Anyone got a simple answer?

Comment: I use  `angular-strap 2.3.12` and `angular-motion 0.4.4` along with `angular 1.6.4` Updating `angular-motion` is important as well...